# To sign out from twitter,Facebook,..in rails

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, session, twitter, omniauth

```
def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed out!"
end
```

In application.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", sessions_destroy_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I have used here devise and omniauth authentication.

The above create method will create the new twitter user or facebook user in my User table. The destroy method will destroy the session of signed in user but it is not signing out from the twitter or facebook account.

I have to sign out from the twitter or facebook account when the call of sign out.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For facebook login and logout verify [#360 Facebook Authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast).

For twitter logout still searching..